# Вывод из бд

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Написал маленький запрос к бд на вывод всех данных из бд, а он выводит только одну первую.

```
  $latters = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM latters");
  $latterslink = mysql_fetch_array($latters);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while($latterslink = mysql_fetch_array($latters)) {
 echo $latterslink[param];
}
```

где `param` - это некий столбец в твоей таблице.

Comment: @cnofss, а откуда у вас берётся переменная $userinfo?

Comment: @MasterAlex Это вывод данных пользователя.

Comment: @MasterAlex это все хорошо работает, выдает то, что надо. При авторизации выводятся данные о пользователе, который вошел на сайт. Даже если я просто в запросе поставлю нужную цифру, он все равно ничего не выводит. В бд все есть, иначе выдавало бы ошибку.

Comment: @MasterAlex я же сказал, что даже если просто цифру поставлю, все равно не работает. Переменная полностью рабочая. Даже если просто сделаю echo $userinfo[id]; то он выдаст мне мой id

Comment: @cnofss, а вам обязательно второй запрос в базе делать внутри цикла while, вроде там нет данных зависимых от переменной цикла?

Comment: О, while убрал и заработало. Спасибо. Запишите в ответ, галочку поставлю, не этому же который ни фига не помог даже...

Comment: @cnofss, я считаю, что на поставленный в теме вопрос он ответил полностью, ;) а я немного помог привести это к правильному виду.